# How to check two condition while using @ConditionalOnProperty or @ConditionalOnExpression

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I need to check that two conditions are satisfied on a YAML property file, while creating a bean. How do I do that, as the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation supports only one property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot SpEL ConditionalOnExpression check multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477251/spring-boot-spel-conditionalonexpression-check-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 53):

Use `@ConditionalOnExpression` annotation and SpEL expression as described here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html.

Example:

```
@Controller
@ConditionalOnExpression("${controller.enabled} and ${some.value} > 10")
public class WebController {
```

Comment: This saved a lot of time !!! thanks a lot

Answer (score 47):

Since from the beginning of `@ConditionalOnProperty` it was possible to check more than one property. The name / value attribute is an array.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty({ "property1", "property2" })
protected static class MultiplePropertiesRequiredConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }

}
```

For simple boolean properties with an AND check you don't need a `@ConditionalOnExpression`.

Comment: This is a trivial case, and won't work when you want `property1=x` and `property1=y` .

Answer (score 15):

You might be interested in the [`AllNestedConditions`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/AllNestedConditions.html) abstract class that was introduced in Spring Boot 1.3.0.  This allows you to create composite conditions where all conditions you define must apply before any `@Bean` are initialized by your `@Configuration` class.

```
public class ThisPropertyAndThatProperty extends AllNestedConditions {

    @ConditionalOnProperty("this.property")
    @Bean
    public ThisPropertyBean thisProperty() {
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty("that.property")
    @Bean
    public ThatPropertyBean thatProperty() {
    }

}
```

Then you can annotate your `@Configuration` like this:

```
@Conditional({ThisPropertyAndThatProperty.class}
@Configuration
```

Comment: `AllNestedCondition` has no no-arg constructor. You need to call super constructor from `ThisPropertyAndThatProperty` constructor like `super(ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION)`.

Answer (score 6):

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{${path.to.property.one:true} and ${path.to.property.two:true}}")
```

both true values are the default value if property is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get any of the above to work for my test:

```
@Slf4j
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE,
    properties = {
        "debug=true",
        "my.property1=false",
        "your.property2.enabled=true"
    })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = AFTER_CLASS)
class MyTest {....}
```

I managed to make it work with:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${my.property1}'=='false' && '${your.property2.enabled}'=='true'")
```

Answer (score -7):

Resolved the issue by using @ConditionalOnExpression for the two properties together.

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${com.property1}${com.property2}'=='value1value2'")
```

Wherein property value in configuration is as below.

Property 1
Name - `com.property1`
Value - `value1`

Property 2
Name - `com.property2`
Value - `value2`

Comment: What about `"${com.property1}=='value1' and ${com.property2}=='value2'"` ?

Comment: counter-example: `com.property = value` and `com.property2 = 1value2`

make the expression == true but is not what the OP is looking for.

95% of the code of applications around the world suck because of this kind of ugly hacks that only bring trouble. As @Navrocky said, the correct solution would be `"${com.property1}=='value1' and ${com.property2}=='value2'"`