# Spring Boot SpEL ConditionalOnExpression check multiple properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

**Question:**

*How can I use Spring Expression Language to check that 2 Boolean properties are true?*

For example, checking that a single property is true would use the syntax:

**Example**

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${property.from.properties.file}")
```

What would be the syntax for checking `property1 == true && property2 == false`? Where the properties can potentially have different values.

The answer from a similar question: [How to check two condition while using @ConditionalOnProperty or @ConditionalOnExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016864/how-to-check-two-condition-while-using-conditionalonproperty-or-conditionalone) concatenates two strings together and performs a check like so:

**Concatenation Solution**

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${com.property1}${com.property2}'=='value1value2'")
```

That syntax seems confusing to someone reading that code and it seems like a hacky solution.  There are some edge cases where the solution fails as well. 
I want to find the proper way to check two separate properties without concatenating the values.

**Note:**
*Also just to be clear, the answer isn't something you can easily search for from what I've seen.  It seems like it would be a really simple answer but it's proving to be fairly elusive.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check two condition while using @ConditionalOnProperty or @ConditionalOnExpression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016864/how-to-check-two-condition-while-using-conditionalonproperty-or-conditionalone)

Comment: @polyakoff that question does not have an accepted answer and does not answer my question.

Comment: "'${com.property1} and ${com.property2}'" ?

Comment: @kuhajeyan can you confirm that syntax works?  I tried the operators "&&" and "and" and I got an error in both cases.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The annotations `@ConditionalOnProperty` and `@ConditionalOnExpression` both do NOT have the `java.lang.annotation.Repeatable` annotation so you would not be able to just add multiple annotations for checking multiple properties.

The following syntax has been tested and works:

**Solution for Two Properties**

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${properties.first.property.enable:true} && ${properties.second.property.startServer:false}")
```

Note the following:

- You need to using colon notation to indicate the default value of
  the property in the expression language statement
- Each property is in a separate expression language block ${}
- The && operator is used outside of the SpEL blocks

It allows for multiple properties that have differing values and can extend to multiple properties.

If you want to check more then 2 values and still maintain readability, you can use the concatenation operator between different conditions you are evaluating:

**Solution for more then 2 properties**

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${properties.first.property.enable:true} " +
        "&& ${properties.second.property.enable:true} " +
        "&& ${properties.third.property.enable:true}")
```

The drawback is that you cannot use a matchIfMissing argument as you would be able to when using the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation so you will have to ensure that the properties are present in the *.properties* or *YAML* files for all your profiles/environments or just rely on the default value

Comment: Assigning the default value really matters. If value is null, then even if you wanna check it for null, you should tell that missing value should be interpreted as null, otherwise it will fail with an SPeL parse error. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that >>${properties.first.property.enable:true} && ${properties.second.property.startServer:false}<< doesn't work. >>${properties.first.property.enable} and ${properties.second.property.startServer:false}==true<< works here

Comment: For me only this worked:
`@ConditionalOnExpression("'${my.property1}'=='false' && '${your.property2.enabled}'=='true'")`

Answer (score 9):

As far as i remember,
You could use this kind of expression:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${com.property1}'.equals('${com.property2}')")
```

for further reading
here is the [link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=spring-xd-master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/server/SharedServerContextConfiguration.java)

if it was helpful, please do comment so that my confusion may also get cleared.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I also need to handle the case where the properties are potentially different values

Answer (score 3):

Can be little bit confusing using boolean properties

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnExpression("${config.integration.materializedCollectionDeleteEnabled:true}  and  ${config.integration.dbTransactionsEnabled:false}")
public DefaultMaterializedCollectionUpdater defaultMaterializedCollectionUpdater(IntegrationConfig integrationConfig, MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    return new DefaultMaterializedCollectionUpdater(integrationConfig, mongoTemplate);
}
```

It may seem like bean should be created when I have properties like

```
config:
  integration:
    dbTransactionsEnabled: false
    materializedCollectionDeleteEnabled: true
```

But bean does not get created because `${property:value}` is giving you default value but not checking if your property has given value. If you want explicitly check property has value then use ==. You still can keep default values though

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnExpression("${config.integration.materializedCollectionDeleteEnabled:true} == true  and  ${config.integration.dbTransactionsEnabled:false} == false")
public DefaultMaterializedCollectionUpdater defaultMaterializedCollectionUpdater(IntegrationConfig integrationConfig, MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    return new DefaultMaterializedCollectionUpdater(integrationConfig, mongoTemplate);
}
```

To debug use `org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.Tokenizer` constructor

Comment: This is a very good example for boolean values.  Here is one example that worked for me. The  == operator did the trick for me.                                                      
@ConditionalOnExpression( "${ldap.auth.enabled} == false and ${camunda.engine.rest.auth.disabled} == false")