# Spring @ConditionalOnExpression with OR statement

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a @ConditionalOnExpression which uses a property from my application.properties. I would like the @ConditionalOnExpression to use a OR condition so that it triggers if one out three different values for the property is there.

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${env.name}'=='prod' or '${env.name}' == 'alsoProd'")
```

I cant seem to get this to work. So, is it even possible to use an OR statement in the @ConditionalOnExpression??

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40497419/5343269

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${env.name}'=='prod'", "'${env.name}' == 'alsoProd'")
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Expression Language (SpEL) allows definition of lists.

As you compare the same value twice you can simply define a list and check if the environment name is in that list.

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("{'prod', 'alsoProd'}.contains('${env.name}')")
```

Answer (score 0):

Example from your question should work properly and it's valid with Spring's documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-operators-logical.

Are you sure that it doesn't work?