# Spring Boot 2.x.x - @ConditionalOnExpression: Expression parsing failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-el

I'm using Spring Boot `2.2.5.RELEASE`. In my `application.properties` file I have the following properties:

```
security.basic.authorize-mode=authenticated
security.basic.enabled=true
```

Since they're no longer customizable because of [simplification of Spring Boot default security configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#security),

[image]

I can't use it via `application.properties`.

I've researched and tried [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40497419/8370915) using annotation `@ConditionalOnExpression` for two properties like:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${security.basic.enabled:true} && ${security.basic.authorize-mode:authenticated}")
```

And by the same logic was this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51257660/8370915).
But it doesn't work for me, because I have `authenticated` instead of values `true/false`:

[image]

So, I've tried to write like:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${security.basic.enabled:true} && ${security.basic.authorize.mode}.equals('authenticated')")
```

it compiles good, but after running the program, I'm getting the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnExpressionCondition.evaluateExpression(OnExpressionCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnExpressionCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnExpressionCondition.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:135) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:61) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:33) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Can I use `@ConditionalOnExpression` or `@ConditionalOnProperty` for multiple properties, but not only for boolean `true/false` values?

**UPD:**
I've added single quotes:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${security.basic.authorize.mode:'authenticated'} && ${security.basic.enabled:true}")
```

[image]

In this case I'm getting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Boolean] for value 'authenticated'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value 'authenticated'
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:70) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value 'authenticated'
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToBooleanConverter.convert(StringToBooleanConverter.java:63) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToBooleanConverter.convert(StringToBooleanConverter.java:31) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:385) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

And also I tried using `environment.getProperty()` for `@ConditionalOnExpression` annotation:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{environment.getProperty('security.basic.authorize.mode') eq('authenticated') && environment.getProperty('security.basic.enabled') eq('true')}")
```

Comment: You don't have an expressin, just 2 value expressions with a default...

Comment: so, can I use these two via specific annotation instead of `application.properties`?

Comment: Do I need to use [@Value](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-defaults) annotation instead of `@ConditionalOnExpression` & `@ConditionalOnProperty`? Looks like I've found [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49714249/8370915), but with `true/false`.

Comment: BUt why do you want to use properties that are no longer supported? If you want security add the websecurityconfigurer else leave it out.

Comment: Because I've upgraded version of Spring Boot, so these properties must be removed from `application.properties` in favor of `websecurityconfigurer` [custom settings](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0). I'm not very sure that I understand how to do the same programmatically. Can you show me an example how to use it for my properties?

Comment: Ditch the properties and just include a security configuration with a rule to only allow authenticated access.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified a bit own answer according to your hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [@M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60831447/spring-boot-2-x-x-conditionalonexpression-expression-parsing-failed/60852253#comment107663476_60831447), I can use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with rules for authenticated access:

```
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration
        extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserInfoDetailsService userInfoDetailsService;

    public SpringSecurityConfiguration_Database(UserInfoDetailsService userInfoDetailsService) {
        this.userInfoDetailsService = userInfoDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder)
            throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userInfoDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/**", "/h2-console")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .realmName("...")
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not instead, as you will still need this configuration class. WIth just the properties it won't work, you can only control if this configuration is applied or not. But if the properties never change (between your diferrent profiles) trying to add them will only add complexity and nothing functional.