# Spring @ConditionalOnProperty havingValue = "value1" or "value2"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I am looking for `configurationOnProperty` usage where I can specify to consider more than one value as shown below

Eg: `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "test.configname", havingValue = "value1" or "value2")`

OR

I would like to know if it is possible to specify `confiugrationOnProperty` with condition of `havingValue != "value3"`

Eg: `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "test.configname", havingValue != "value3")`

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve any one of the above in `spring boot` configuration.

Comment: maybe duplicate of [how-to-check-two-condition-while-using-conditionalonproperty-or-conditionalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016864/how-to-check-two-condition-while-using-conditionalonproperty-or-conditionalone)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Spring Boot provides [`AnyNestedCondition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/AnyNestedCondition.html) for created a condition that will match when any nested condition matches. It also provides [`AllNestedConditions`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/AllNestedConditions.html) and [`NoneNestedConditions`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/NoneNestedConditions.html) for matching when all nested conditions or no nested conditions match respectively.

For your specific case where you want to match a value of `value1` or `value2` you would create an `AnyNestedCondition` like this:

```
class ConfigNameCondition extends AnyNestedCondition {

    public ConfigNameCondition() {
        super(ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION);
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "test.configname", havingValue = "value1")
    static class Value1Condition {

    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "test.configname", havingValue = "value2")
    static class Value2Condition {

    }

}
```

And then use it with `@Conditional`, like this for example:

```
@Bean
@Conditional(ConfigNameCondition.class)
public SomeBean someBean() {
    return new SomeBean();
}
```

As shown in the javadoc for the nested condition annotations (linked to above) the nested conditions can be of any type. There's no need for them to all be of the same type as they are in this particular case.

Comment: it looks awful. Do you have ticket to make @ConditionalOnProperty repeatable ?

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2541). It's not that easy to implement though as some will want AND semantics and others will want OR. Nested conditions may not be aesthetically pleasing, but `AnyNestedCondition`, `AllNestedConditions` and `NoneNestedConditions` give you a lot of flexibility.

Comment: It is flexible but not user friendly)

Comment: You have the same logic(AND) for @Qualifier and everyone is happy

Comment: Everyone apart from the person who asked this question and wanted `OR`, hence the use of `AnyNestedCondition` above.

Comment: But why don't make it consistent with @Qualifier?  It is a mess from my view

Comment: The issue that I've linked to above has not been declined and, if you read it, you'll see that a change to Spring Framework would also be required. Rather than making a series of derogatory remarks, perhaps you'd like to do something constructive and contribute some pull requests?

Comment: Andy, sorry. I didn't want you to be upset. I just wanted to emphasize that it is to complex for framework client. I don't know so much about BPPs and BFPPs and other internal spring framework stuff so I am afraid I won't suggest any pull request) Moreover I am not a Jourgen Holler who is an author of 80% of spring core source as far as I know.

Comment: want to add that with newer versions of `Spring`, annotation `ConditionalOnProperty` should be updated `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "test.configname", havingValue = "value1")`

Answer (score 20):

The annotations `@ConditionalOnProperty` and `@ConditionalOnExpression` both do NOT have the `java.lang.annotation.Repeatable` annotation so you would not be able to just add multiple annotations for checking multiple properties.

The following syntax has been tested and works:

**Solution for Two Properties**

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${properties.first.property.enable:true} && ${properties.second.property.startServer:false}")
```

Note the following:

- You need to using colon notation to indicate the default value of
  the property in the expression language statement
- Each property is in a separate expression language block ${}
- The && operator is used outside of the SpEL blocks

It allows for multiple properties that have differing values and can extend to multiple properties.

If you want to check more then 2 values and still maintain readability, you can use the concatenation operator between different conditions you are evaluating:

**Solution for more then 2 properties**

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${properties.first.property.enable:true} " +
        "&& ${properties.second.property.enable:true} " +
        "&& ${properties.third.property.enable:true}")
```

The drawback is that you cannot use a matchIfMissing argument as you would be able to when using the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation so you will have to ensure that the properties are present in the *.properties* or *YAML* files for all your profiles/environments or just rely on the default value

Taken from here [Spring Boot SpEL ConditionalOnExpression check multiple properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477251/spring-boot-spel-conditionalonexpression-check-multiple-properties/40497419#40497419)

Answer (score 6):

> I am looking for `configurationOnProperty` usage where I can specify to
>   consider more than one value

You can use [Condition interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html) of `Spring 4.0`.

This interface has a method `matches(...)` which you can use.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata;

public class TestCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        String testValue = (context.getEnvironment().getProperty("test.configname");
        return "value1".equalsIgnoreCase("testValue") || "value2".equalsIgnoreCase("testValue");
    }

}
```

And then use `TestCondition` inside your `@Configuration` like below :

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

      @Conditional(value=TestCondition .class)
      public MyBean getTestConfigBean() {
          //TODO YOUR CODE;
      }

}
```

> I would like to know if it is possible to specify
>   confiugrationOnProperty with condition of havingValue != "value3"

```
public class TestCondition2 implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        String testValue = (context.getEnvironment().getProperty("test.configname");
        return ! "value3".equalsIgnoreCase("testValue");
    }

}
```

And then use it like this :

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

      @Conditional(value=TestCondition2 .class)
      public MyBean getTestConfigBean() {
          //TODO YOUR CODE;
      }

}
```

Comment: all those equalsIgnoreCase("testValue") should be equalsIgnoreCase(testValue), you test against the variable, not the string

Answer (score 1):

To have complext conditions you can use `@ConditionalOnExpression` and use SpEl query there like

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{ T(java.util.Arrays).asList('value1', 'value2').contains('${test.configname}')}")
```

or use

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${test.configname}' ne 'value3'")
```

To more info take a look https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditional-annotations

Answer (score 0):

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${"test.configname"}' == 'value1'" + 
                      "OR '${"test.configname"}' == 'value2'")
```

you can use the key & value from constants as well

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${" + CONFIG_NAME + "}' == '" + VALUE1 + "'" + 
                      "OR '${" + CONFIG_NAME + "}' == '" + VALUE2 + "'")
```

You can play with parenthesis & negation to check multiple match values along with non matching, if you need different condition