# Spring Boot - autoconfigure if any property with prefix exists

Tags: spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

I'm trying to register an autoconfiguration with `@ConditionalOnProperty`. This configuration should be created when there is any property with a predefined prefix.

For example, this configuration should be created when there is one of the properties listed below

```
test.property.any-text-goes-here.some-nested-property=test
test.property.nested.nested-two=another
```

I've tried to use `@ConditionalOnProperty` with `name=test.property`, but it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe this can be sorted out using `@ConditionalOnExpression`, but I have no idea how SpEL expression should look like.

I'm wondering if there a way to achieve this without the need of implementing custom `Condition`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not possible without creating a custom `Condition`. This can also help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51257432/spring-conditionalonproperty-havingvalue-value1-or-value2?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible. `@ConditionalOnProperty` evaluates and compares only final property values in flat structure. It does not work on objects :(