# How to configure @ConditionalOnProperty with multiple string matching conditions?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

I want to load a bean based on two String property value matching conditions.

Egg:

> application.properties

```
foo.test.alpha=sodium
foo.test.beta=chlorine
```

> Bean Config:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "foo.test", name = "alpha", havingValue = "sodium")
public DefaultErrorHandler defaultErrorHandler(final DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishRecoverer) {

    // do something
}
```

**In the above bean config am able to check only value of foo.test.aplpha=sodium, but how to add foo.test.beta=chlorine matching in the above config ?**

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016864/how-to-check-two-condition-while-using-conditionalonproperty-or-conditionalone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check two condition while using @ConditionalOnProperty or @ConditionalOnExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016864/how-to-check-two-condition-while-using-conditionalonproperty-or-conditionalone)