# Spring Boot 2.x.x - Combine 2 conditions in @ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-bean

I have the following interface :

```
@Primary
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "ms.couchbase.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "iiams.switch.iiamsSingleProcessIdPer100", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public interface AsyncCommonRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<CouchbaseDocument, Long> { }
```

Of course this does not compile.
All I want is to combine somehow the two `@ConditionalOnProperty`. Should I use `@ConditionalOnExpression`?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check two condition while using @ConditionalOnProperty or @ConditionalOnExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016864/how-to-check-two-condition-while-using-conditionalonproperty-or-conditionalone)

Comment: Actually no, I don't know how to use havingValue and matchIfMissing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `AllNestedConditions` to combine two or more conditions:

```java
class AsyncCommonRepositoryCondition extends AllNestedConditions {

    AsyncCommonRepositoryCondition() {
        super(ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION);
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "ms.couchbase.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    static class CouchbaseEnabled {

    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "iiams.switch.iiamsSingleProcessIdPer100", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    static class SingleProcessIdPer100 {

    }

}
```

This condition can then be used on your repository:

```java
@Primary
@Conditional(AsyncCommonRepositoryCondition.class)
public interface AsyncCommonRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<CouchbaseDocument, Long> { }
```